# how to use php in big xml file?

Tags: php, html, mysql, xml

I want use php to fetch data from mysql database and set values in xml file, I try different things such as

```
libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
$myXMLData=
    "<?xml version='1.0'?>............(12000lines).............";
$xml = simplexml_load_string($myXMLData);
if ($xml === false) {
    echo "Failed loading XML: ";
    foreach(libxml_get_errors() as $error) {
        echo "<br>", $error->message;
    }
} else {
    print_r($xml);
}
?>
```

and  etc but nothing work. The above methode show error in alot of lines as xml file is too big as you can see it image.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8oehY.png)
Please let me know if there is any way to use PHP in xml file. Thank you

[thats the file which displays errors](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1JIc9aiAHZjXRdvvjpYojdxXLxyhn8ZXP)

Comment: When you say it shows errors in the code you have, could you show what these errors are (don't need to repeat the same error, but a sample would be good)

Comment: As i mentioned above there are 12000+ lines code, when i remove the spaces between tag<> such <style> and other error moves to another lines and it keep doing it :(

Comment: Failed loading XML: 
attributes construct error 
Couldn't find end of Start Tag NamedRange line 1980

Comment: OK - The error looks more like there may be a problem with the XML rather than just the size.  Is there anyway you can let me have a copy of the data (something like pastebin or any other web site may do it)

Comment: sure sir, i just edited my question. you can find it in the end of question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a problem with the data at this element...

```
<NamedRange ss:Name='Print_Area' ss:RefersTo='='MSI APR-18'!R1C2:R94C21'/>
```

It may be that in processing it, the double quotes have been replaced by single quotes and this means that the ss:RefersTo attribute has an illegal value.

You could just edit this line to be

```
<NamedRange ss:Name='Print_Area' ss:RefersTo=\"='MSI APR-18'!R1C2:R94C21\"/>
```

and it should work.

Comment: Thank you for time, now it give error 
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'MSI' (T_STRING) in

Comment: Sorry - forgot it was already in quotes... will update answer.

Comment: Changed to `\"` to escape the double quotes

Comment: Sir its generating xml code while i need XML file in output :(
is there any way to get xml file instead of this code.

Comment: I copy that all code and paste in notepad and saved it as xml but it gives error and not giving me report which i need

Comment: Not sure what you mean, but don't use `print_r($xml);`, use `echo $xml->asXML();`

Comment: Sir actually I want to generate xml file, in the format which I share in question(image)

Comment: Sorry but that is a whole new problem. You cant to generate quite a complex format from the data.  This will take a lot of time and coding to lay it out just like that.